# File exists but is inaccessible via script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, apache2

I am receiving the following error when trying to display the contents of `/var/log/apache2/error_log` in a bash script:

```
more: stat of /var/log/apache2/error_log failed: No such file or directory
```

Yet, I can run the command `more` on the command line and it works fine (sometimes - please see below).

I've checked that the filename is correct in the bash script (actually I cut and pasted it to ensure this).

The bash script is simply:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
more /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

I've also tried:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sudo more /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

but I still receive the same error.

On the command line, it will only work when using the auto-complete for the filename.  When I type the command and the filename fully, it will not find the file.  Yet, when I type `more /var/log/a`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and auto-complete `apache2` and `error_log` (or even just `error_log`) it works fine. It seems that it will only work when auto-completing the filename. So it appears not to be a permission error per se.

Any insight into why this is occurring is very much appreciated.

Comment: The file is supposed to be called `error.log`, not `error_log`.

Comment: What does `type -a more` say? Can you try with `less` or `cat`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of these commands: i) `ls -l /var/log/apache2/*error*` and ii) `ls /var/log/apache2/*error* | od -c`. The file probably has a non-printing character in its name and that's why using the file name fails but completion works.

Comment: It was indeed as Jos mentioned.  I inadvertently confused the error.log with error_log (another file I created under by username).  Tx Jos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filename changed to error.log instead of the user create error_log.

Comment: What does it mean? Is your problem solved?